# Injecting ActivatedRoute in a component constructor

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I am creating an angular 5 app and want to pass the ActivatedRoute as a parameter in a constructor. Before doing so the app was running, but now I am getting an error:

> compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for
>   DashboardComponent: (?).
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15700)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15535)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:15020)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:15848)
>       at eval (compiler.js:15829)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (compiler.js:15828)
>       at eval (compiler.js:15783)
>       at Array.forEach ()

My routing component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The component in cause:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, ActivatedRoute, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Player } from "../../player";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']  
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {  
  private _router;
  model = new Player("");  
  submitted = false;

  constructor(router: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this._router = router;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() { 
    this.submitted = true;
    this._router.navigate(['/game']);
  }

  get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.model); }
}
```

App.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatrixComponent } from './components/matrix/matrix.component';
import { SquareComponent } from './components/square/square.component';
import { PlayerComponent } from './components/player/player.component';
import { BoatContainerComponent } from './components/boat-container/boat-container.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { GameComponent } from './components/game/game.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MatrixComponent,
    SquareComponent,
    PlayerComponent,
    BoatContainerComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    GameComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Import AppRoutingModule into AppModule.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, // <-- here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: I have that module in my app.module.ts, have a look again to see if you spot something wrong, I have updated the post with the app.module.ts

Comment: you seem to be using the activated route as a router in the onSubmit() method. Are you sure you do not want to inject the Router? Because the Router class has  the .naviagte() method, not the ActivatedRoute.

Comment: I added the Router, but the error remains (I am new to angular)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up to resolve the issue. It was happening the same if passing the ActivatedRoute (or other class like Router) in the app.module.ts constructor. I added the import of the Router and RouterModule. Here is the code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, RouterModule,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatrixComponent } from './components/matrix/matrix.component';
import { SquareComponent } from './components/square/square.component';
import { PlayerComponent } from './components/player/player.component';
import { BoatContainerComponent } from './components/boat-container/boat-container.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { GameComponent } from './components/game/game.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MatrixComponent,
    SquareComponent,
    PlayerComponent,
    BoatContainerComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    GameComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(router: ActivatedRoute) {
    //console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 2));
 }
}
```